# Elasticsearch can't write to log files

Tags: linux, logging, elasticsearch, linux-mint

I would like to activate logs of elasticsearch .

When I run elasticsearch binaries, I realize that I have problems with logging : the configuration cannot be loaded !

Here is the output :

```
~ $ sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
Failed to configure logging...
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Failed to load logging configuration
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.resolveConfig(LogConfigurator.java:117)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:81)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupLogging(Bootstrap.java:94)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:32)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:144)
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:97)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1686)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:109)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:69)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2602)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.resolveConfig(LogConfigurator.java:107)
    ... 4 more
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (node).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/sigar/libsigar-x86-linux.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
```

I am running under linuxmint 17 and using latest ES.

Answer (score 40):

If you installed elasticsearch using a package manager like `yum` or `apt-get` you should not start elasticsearch this way. Try to use the service: for instance `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch` or using the command `sudo service elasticsearch start`

You should also check if the logging.yml file is at the location mentioned in the stack trace:`/usr/share/elasticsearch/config`

Using `sudo` to start elasticsearch is not good, you could do `sudo elasticsearch` to run as the elasticsearch user, but I prefer to use the service call as described in the second sentence.

Hope that helps

Comment: However, if you want start the 2nd node in the same machine, you should start it with `sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch --default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch/`.

Comment: This was my issue. Installed on LM 17 with the .deb file, but launching through the service worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Your `elasticsearch.yml` file as well as `logging.yml` file will be in the `/etc/elasticsearch` folder.

Create a config folder in your `elasticsearch` folder in `/usr/share` and move the .yml files to the config folder

Now run `/bin/elasticsearch start` and it will work.

Comment: I find a symlink is easier: `ln -s /etc/elasticsearch/ /usr/share/elasticsearch/config`

Answer (score 7):

Following this worked for me.

Your elasticsearch.yml file as well as logging.yml file will be in the /etc/elasticsearch folder.

Create a config folder in your elasticsearch folder in /usr/share and move the .yml files to the config folder

Comment: I created symlinks, since configs usually reside in /etc and I'd forget where they were meant to be later (like `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml -> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`)

Answer (score 4):

You can do symlinks, but if you simply want to point elasticsearch to the desired config directory, you can use the following:

`/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch --default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch/`

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed elasticsearch in Debian systems using dpkg, the default configuration can be found at `/etc/elasticsearch/`

You will have 2 yml files:

- `elasticsearch.yml`
- `logging.yml`

You can edit the elasticsearch file (changing access right or copying file into your main elasticsearch directory). To configure your log path (l.167).

```
    #path.logs: /path/to/logs
    #e.g:        
    path.logs: /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs
```

Make sure you have right access on it.
Then try

```
    cd /usr/share/elasticsearch/ 
    bin/elasticsearch start
```

and  check the `publish_adress` given in terminal

You can also define more parameters. Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed a .deb and want to start sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch

You have to do :

```
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch

sudo ln -s /etc/elasticsearch config
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have installed your elasticsearch using yum or apt-get
The best way of doing this is by typing:

```
$ sudo service elasticsearch start
```

or anything similar, like the way you would start services like nginx, etc.

It works for me.

Comment: Is not the solution or the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run it in foreground, but not as service just specify configuration directory explicitly.

```
$ /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch
```

In this case elasticsearch will be able to find all your config files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to start elasticsearch from the tar download so that I can run multiple separate instances easily without service definitions.

What worked for me was to go up a directory and launch elasticsearch using `bin/elasticsearch` instead of just `elasticsearch` while being in the bin directory.

Now it started up no problem without any symlinks, service files, or other changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running elasicsearch with the user `elasticsearch`, so I used this command:

```
sudo su elasticsearch -c './bin/elasticsearch -d --default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch'
```

from the dir where elasticsearch is installed. Had to do:

```
sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch .
```

in there though because otherwise it won't have write access to the log files. I don't know how this would work via the debian startup scripts, but this seems to work fine like this.

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same issue and was wondering how they could miss it in the installation script of elastic search. So, after some digging here is what I found:

1. It looks like you installed elastic search using yum or apt-get or else you would have had the 'config' directory under ES_HOME.
2. Checking the init.d/elasticsearch shows the following:

   `DAEMON_OPTS="-d -p $PID_FILE --default.path.home=$ES_HOME --default.path.logs=$LOG_DIR --default.path.data=$DATA_DIR --default.path.conf=$CONF_DIR"`

   :

   `# Start Daemon`

   `start-stop-daemon -d $ES_HOME --start -b --user "$ES_USER" -c "$ES_USER" --pidfile "$PID_FILE" --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS`
3. So, all the variables are properly initialized and then passed as command line parameters.
4. So, the best way for you to start is using the service:

   `>sudo service elasticsearch start`
5. It will make sure that all the config and log parameters are passed to the main command.
6. Check logs under `/var/log/$NAME` that would be '/var/log/elasticsearch`