# How can I run elasticsearch on a docker container using supervisor?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, supervisord

I ran into some problems running elasticsearch on a debian-based container, a combination of [not being able to find log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975895/elasticsearch-cant-write-to-log-files) and [not being able to run as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920801/how-to-run-elasticsearch-2-1-1-as-root-user-in-linux-machine). But even symlinking the config files didn't work for me. I was able to get it running and thought it might be helpful for somebody.

I installed elasticsearch with this command:

```
wget -qO - https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb http://packages.elastic.co/elasticsearch/2.x/debian stable main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elasticsearch-2.x.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y elasticsearch \
    && update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10
```

Answer (score 3):

### Update: See comment about deprecation from @Morfie

> Setting the es.insecure.allow.root flag has been removed: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/3ccd59592a46aa26b0675025248a69b4ade3d516

### Previous Answer:

Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir /usr/share/elasticsearch/config \
    && ln /etc/elasticsearch/logging.yml /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/ \
    && ln /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/ \
    && chmod 774 /usr/share/elasticsearch/config

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

And elasticsearch entry in supervisord.conf

```
[program:elasticsearch]
command=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Des.insecure.allow.root=true
```

Comment: Setting the es.insecure.allow.root flag has been removed: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/3ccd59592a46aa26b0675025248a69b4ade3d516

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer. I don't have any solution now and since I'm not using elastic search via supervisor for anything now it's not a priority for me.